# how to deploy spring REST application (back-end)and angular application (web)separately on same production server

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, spring-rest

If I create two different application i.e back-end in spring REST and front-end in angular and deploy it my production server (ubuntu)through SSH i,e Putty each time i need to copy the dist folder of angular application to my web content folder of Spring REST application. By doing  that any change in angular application ,we need to copy and paste the DIST folder each time to our REST application and generate war file and then deploy it.If you change anything at angular side, you need to copy paste dist folder all time and then you can deploy it which is a major drawback of this approach so kindly provide me any alternative .So I want to deploy both application separately on the same server so that any change in one should not impact in other.

Answer (score 0):

In this video, I was showing how to deploy an Angular app under the Spring Boot server: https://youtu.be/k8r76d8QzXs?t=2237. In your case, you'd need to replace the copy command with the one that runs the SSH command.

Each time the Angular app changes, just re-run the npm run build command to deploy the new version of Angular bundles under the Spring Server. No re-deployment on the server-side is needed.